# Returning column header corresponding to matched value in separate sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sheet 1

| Name | Gender |
| --- | --- |
| w | 0 |
| e | 1 |
| r | 2 |
| t | 4 |
| y | 6 |
| u | 2 |
| i | NoMatch |
| q | 1 |
| w | 1 |
| e | 1 |
| r | 2 |

Sheet 2 - Note sheet 2 has 2 "w" under Name column

| Name | Male 1 | Female 2 | other 3 | other 4 | other 5 | Donotknow 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| w | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| w | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| a | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| q | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| r | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| e | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| t | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| y | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| u | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I am using this formula in Sheet 1 under Gender:

```
=IFERROR(FILTER({1,2,3,4,5,6},INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$G$10,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$10,0),0)=1),"NoMatch")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with the fact that a zero stands for 'No Match', then try:
[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=BYROW(A2:A12,LAMBDA(a,MIN(IF((D2:D10=a)*E2:J10,SEQUENCE(,6),""))))
```

If not, then change too:

```
=LET(X,BYROW(A2:A12,LAMBDA(a,MIN(IF((D2:D10=a)*E2:J10,SEQUENCE(,6),"")))),IF(X,X,"No Match"))
```